# Could we have lists within favorites?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I find that over time I accumulate a lot of favorite questions.

Is there a feature in the works to sub-classify favorites into specific folders, the way browser bookmarks work?

Comment: If you want something that works the way browser bookmarks work, *use browser bookmarks*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Browser bookmarks are specific to each browser and each machine. I want this feature on stackexchange precisely so that I can use it across browsers and machines.

Comment: Google Bookmarks. Firefox Sync.Pocket.